# can not .getJSON request to work

Tags: javascript, jquery

My state legislature website offers a restful api.

What is the correct javascript / jquery code to fetch the value of kslegislature.org/li/api/v5/rev-1/bill_listing/
into a variable?

I can not seem to construct a working .getJSON request to pull the data.

Ultimately I want to be able to work with values like

```
var kslegBills = RETURNED DATA;
console.log(kslegbills.content[1].BILLNO)
```

complete API guide available here: http://www.google.com/url?sa=D&q=http://kslegislature.org/kliss_restian_interface_guide_v5.odt

A gentle shove in the right direction would be greatly appreciated.

```
jQuery.getJSON("http://www.kslegislature.org/li/api/v5/rev-1/bill_listing/&callback=?", [], function(data, textStatus) { var kslegbills = data; alert(textStatus); } )
```

**UPDATE:**

Thanks to @JackWinks I was able to get a working request through a PHP wrapper. Working model at http://kansasgrassroots.com/files/kslegbills/

It works in chrome, but not firefox or safari. I suspect it is because of the large size of the request that FF and Safari are timing out before data is returned.

Comment: Jake, it's generally useful on this site if you can post some code you have tried.

Comment: Please show us the code you've written so far.

Comment: Thanks griegs - here is the closest I've gotten... This at least returns the data, but I've not figured out how to pass the data in to a variable..  `jQuery.getJSON("http://www.kslegislature.org/li/api/v5/rev-1/bill_listing/&callback=?", [], function(data, textStatus) {
 var kslegbills = data;
 alert(textStatus);
}
)`

Comment: Be gentle. I'm such a noob. Trying not to get discouraged. Be verbose in your explanation please so I can learn.

Comment: and what does the alert give you?

Comment: I can't see that the alert ever triggers. The only notice I get in the console (firebug) is "invalid label 'content ["  Which comes from the data reported back from the API

Comment: if you are not passing data no need for `[]` in the place of second argument just try with `jQuery.getJSON("http://www.kslegislature.org/li/api/v5/rev-1/bill_listing/&callback=?", function(data, textStatus) { var kslegbills = data; ale`

Comment: $.getJSON("http://www.kslegislature.org/li/api/v5/rev-1/bill_listing/?jsoncallback=?", function (data) { alert(data); }) is not working for me so not sure that's the issue @3nigma

Comment: I don't think that API is set up to be cross-domain accessible.  From what I see in the spec, there is no mention of jsonp, and when requesting the domain with callback=?, I get a 503 error.

If you want, you can read up on the same-origin policy:  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy

There is a general workaround, where you proxy the request through your server:
http://jquery-howto.blogspot.com/2009/04/cross-domain-ajax-querying-with-jquery.html

Comment: @griegs yup i though just in case...

Comment: Strange.. It seems back up now. No longer returning 503 - now 200.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't find any key word about 'jsonp' in that document, so does that api support jsonp?